# Loading a list from database using eclipselink jpa

Tags: database, jpa, eclipselink, rcp

I have three tables in a derby database. Schedule, EmployeeSchedule, EmployeeScheduleInfo.
Schedule has a list of EmployeeSchedule and EmployeeSchedule has a list of EmployeeScheduleInfo.

I am using eclipselink jpa and i generated my entities and controllers from netbeans. My problem is when i load a Schedule object from database the list of EmployeeScheduleInfo objects in all EmployeeSchedule objects are not loaded, when i debug this i see

```
{IndirectList: not instantiated}
```

Comment: Try providing more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1:M and ManyToMany relationships are lazy by default in JPA.  That means you need to access the relationship for them to be fetched - call size() on the collection to view it in a debugging environment.  You can also prefetch the collection in the initial query using 'fetch join' in the JPQL or an EclipseLink eclipselink.join-fetch query hint:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_(ELUG)#Join_Fetch